# MySql FOUND_ROWS() returning 195 regardless

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, java-6

I'm selecting data from a database by mean of a storedprocedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select(...)

BEGIN

...

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS x,y,z, FROM ....;

END
```

and then retrieve the number of rows found by mean of this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rows() 

BEGIN

    SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

END
```

This works perfectly well when I call both procedures from the command line:

```
CALL select("x", y, z);
```

yields the correct set of data,

```
CALL rows;
```

yields the correct number of rows found.

However, when I have a Java application make the calls, rows() consistently returns 195.

```
if (c != null) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(statement);
        result = new Matrix(ps.executeQuery());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        errorroutine
    }
} else errorroutine;
return result;
```

What's up? Is 195 an error code, if so, why and what for?

Comment: Not sure why you haven't shared any Java detail but... 1) MySQL doesn't inject error messages in the middle of data sets. 2) Perhaps your Java code makes another select in between.

Comment: No it doesn't, the two calls are immediately  consecutive, both using this Java routine: 

    (given Connection c and Matrix result, a receptacle for resultsets)      
    
    if (c != null) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(statement);
            result = new Matrix(ps.executeQuery());
        } catch(SQLException e) { errorroutine } 
    } else errorroutine;
    return result;

That's all.